# CSS grid for database items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make elements from my database in grid sequence using css, but all items are moved to the left instead of grind [image: this is what the site looks like.]

I tried all ways to grid the items but it all flopped.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var html = "";
 html += "<center>";
 html += "<div id='post'><div id='post-head'>";
 html += snap.val().title;
 html += "</div> <div id='post-id'>  <p>";
 html += snap.val().post;
 html += "</p></div>";
 var pic = snap.val().image;
 if (pic != "empty") {
   html += "<div id='post-img'>";
   html += "<img src='"+pic+"' id='post-pic'>";
   html += "</div>";
   html += "<p align='right' id='snal'> By : Havoshing Admin</p>";
   html += "<br><small id='gray'>";
   html += snap.val().time1;
   html += "</small>";
 } else {
   html += "<br><small id='gray'>";
   html += snap.val().time1;
   html += "</small>";
 }
 html += "</div>";
 html += "</center><br><br><br>";
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += html;
```

This is my css code:

```
#content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

Please I need help figuring out what wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem similar to yours when I used grid, my solution was ( justify-content: center;) so it worked and one more thing, here (grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;) you are dividing your content by metada, I believe this is what is throwing your body to the left, hope it helps you :) .

bro, I believe your block is not being centered because you are still doing it in two
grid-template-columns
when you use this css tag you divide your grid, if you put repeat(2, 1fr) it understands that you are dividing your column in two(2).
when we use grid-template-columns we are saying how many columns we want for our grid(2, 1fr) is equal to "divide grid two", grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; "divide by two", grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%; "divide by two", do you understand?
in your case I think you want only one column and center it, I would use:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 90%;
gap: 10%;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: What should I change the grid-template-columns to?

Comment: I have added justify center to the code but it's still not working. Look at my new code `#content {
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(250px, auto);
  }`

Comment: I had to complement in the answer because here the characters are limited